# How to create a additional field on a SQL table that indicates the increase on the previous highest value only

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, sum, display

I am using an existing table that contains values on items where the value changes on certain days, either increasing  or decreasing. I need to sum the value based on the value increasing from the previous highest value only where it uses the first value as the initial threshold. I've been trying to do this dynamically.

Current Table Structure is as (A)
Trying to achieve (B)

[image: Current Table Structure - A]
[image: Trying to Achieve - B]

I've tried to use a max() over partition to flag the highest value although seem to be stuck at this point

```
SELECT a.Client_ID, a.Value_Amount_Change_Date, a.Value_Amount,
       (case when max(a.Value_Amount) over (partition by a.Client_ID) = Value
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Last_Highest_Value
FROM [Client_DB].[dbo].[Value_Tracking] a
WHERE a.Account_Num IN ('A1234', 'A6789')
GROUP BY a.Client_ID, a.Value_Amount_Change_Date, a.Value_Amount;
```

Expected result set must include an additional column which only indicates the value based on the increase on the previous highest value using the initial value as the initial value to compare against

Comment: Your code looks like SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative maximum, but you want to exclude the current row's value.  So:

```
select a.*,
       (case when a > max(value) over (partition by clientid order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
             then a - max(value) over (partition by clientid order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
        end) as increment_over_running_max
from a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance however this doesn't seem to work - seems like a syntax issue in the code you sent me.

Comment: @Nitesh_R . . . I see no obvious syntax error.  Can you set up a db<>fiddle?  And explain what the error is.